# Search the column name(s) for a specific row value in a table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table "ABCD" which has 20 different columns by the name of my employees (This is the best possible table structure for this organisation as per requirement), Now i have a situation where need to write a SQL query to find the "Column names" for a specific row (say with id 3), which has a particular value (say c).

```
ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6
--------------------------------------------
1  | A    | B    | C    | C    | B    | A
2  | C    | B    | A    | A    | C    | B
3  | B    | A    | C    | B    | A    | C
```

I need to get all "column names" which has value "c" in row with id "3".

Comment: The question is tagged as MySQL and SQL Server.  Which is it?

Comment: Who stated this requirement? This is a very bad table design. Imagine getting another employee ...

Comment: I have a database with tables like this that I have to administer - it makes me cry every time I look at it.

Comment: You shouldn't want have such a table layout (even after the renaming your columns). If it's a many-to-many relation you should have three tables. Then such queries are very simple. _Give me the name of the columns of a row with a special value_ isn't a suitable task a relational database is made for.

Comment: @JustinHelgerson well this question is regarding sql query for any kind of sql server.

Comment: @VMai - It's not always feasible to change table designs after the fact.  It may not be a trivial change (perhaps dozens of applications are impacted) and it could potentially cost *a lot* of $$$ to fix.  You're not answering any of the questions at hand.

Comment: @JustinHelgerson Because of that I'm writing comments and not an answer.

Comment: @VMai consider this to be a fixed table structure for the lifetime, my main concern is, is there a way to get the column names by the query in these kind of situations... Table structure is just used to define these kind of situations!

Comment: @Aditya You can i.e. write a function to get the list of the column names.

Comment: "This is the best possible table structure for this organisation as per requirement" Yeah, right.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's silly

Comment: @strawberry this is a worst structure for a table, but what my concern is, whether is it possible to get column name by the row value, or all DBMS are designed only as to get row value by column name.

Comment: @Aditya Yes, it is possible, and when you've decided what database you're using, you might get a more detailed answer.

Comment: @Aditya MySQL and SQL Server are two different types of a DBMS.  MySQL is owned by Oracle and SQL Server is owned by Microsoft.  While there are similarities between the two they are still very different and the code you write will be different.  Nobody can give you an answer because nobody knows what database you're actually using (i.e. what type of code does one give you?) and you also haven't shown effort in your question to solve the problem yourself.  If you can show both of those things you will likely get help from the community.

Answer (score 2):

you should reconsider DB design

```
    select 'col1' from abcd where id=3 and col1='C'
    union
    select 'col2' from abcd where id=3 and col2='C'
    union
    ...
```

It would be easy for you to generate this script dynamically in PHP

Comment: @Aditya For generate sql dynamically is SQL DB engine dependant.